# How to reload app.component on event in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4, reload

I'm stuck with the following problem.

app.component.ts is listening to event 'login' which works fine. But, when then event is firing I want to reload my app.component-page as I want to show a different side menu when a user is logged in.

I found some examples with Content but Content is not included in @ionic/angular anymore.

Has someone a working example? This would me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Following my environment infos

Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reloading the page which is not a best practice, you should bind the menu to a list of data that you can change depending on the logged in status.

If you want to make structural changes as well then you can just put those on a `*ngIf` for the two versions.

This tutorial [shows how to bind the menu](https://petercoding.com/ionic/2019/05/05/side-menu-in-ionic4/) from an array of pages.

You just set up a data structure to hold the menu items:

```
sideMenu()
  {
    this.navigate =
    [
      {
        title : "Home",
        url   : "/home",
        icon  : "home"
      },
      {
        title : "Chat",
        url   : "/chat",
        icon  : "chatboxes"
      },
      {
        title : "Contacts",
        url   : "/contacts",
        icon  : "contacts"
      },
    ]
  }
```

And then loop it on the front end:

```
    <ion-list *ngFor="let pages of navigate">
      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="true">
        <ion-item [routerLink]="pages.url" routerDirection="forward">
            <ion-icon [name]="pages.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
               {{pages.title}} 
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check the article and will try to do according.

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider upvoting as well, otherwise this doesn't count towards my Ionic4 tag badge (no idea why stackoverflow decided to rank it like that)